# At what altitude, on land, do our ears pop?

Tags: medical, altitude, humor

So, it's obvious that our ears pop when we go into deep water or fly high in a plane but at what altitude on land do our ears pop? I need to know for a book.

Comment: This is pretty subjective, my ears often don't pop at all on flights. Also, when swimming, ears don't usually "pop" unless you do it purposely. It may cause the person quite a bit of pain until they figure out how to pop their ears.

Comment: My ears usually pop with the 500 ft elevation change on my drive to and from the airport from which I am based. However, they rarely pop when I am flying even with 2000+ feet of cabin pressure change.

Comment: It's more related to the rate of change of pressure, rather than the absolute pressure. If you climb an 18000ft mountain over the course of a week, your ears won't noticeably pop.

Comment: Your ears pop when your eustachian tubes equalize pressure.  This can be induced by intentional muscular action, and therefore has no set point at which they pop.  There may be some pilots who clear the pressure differential every few seconds during climbs without even thinking about it out of habit.  I can sit here in my computer chair and pop my ears  about twice per second if I try to.

Comment: Could just as equally be closed as opinion based.